# File descriptor disappearing/nullifying

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault, fopen, scanf

I am using Debian and have written a veeeery simple file parsing program in C. The file I want to open is about 32k lines long, with a strict format:

```
number,number\n
number,number\n
and so on ...
```

My code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char data = 0;
    int addr = 0;
    char buf[50] = {0};

    FILE* myfile = fopen("eelocdump.txt", "r");

    if(myfile == NULL)
    {
        printf("File open error\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets(buf, 50, myfile ) != NULL)
    {
        sscanf(buf, "%5d,%3d\n", &addr, &data);
        printf("%d,%d\n", addr, data);
    }

    fclose(myfile);

    return 0;
}
```

For some odd reasons I do not understand, my code reads the first line of the file, writes it out, then segfaults. After about an hour spent on it, I found out that the call to sscanf caused the file descriptor to be set to NULL.

I have found a "fix" that I hardly dare to name so:

```
    while (fgets(buf, 50, myfile) != NULL)
    {
        sscanf(buf, "%5d,%3d\n", &addr, &data);
        printf("%d,%d\n", addr, data);

        myfile = myfile;
    }
```

Adding this obvious statement makes my code work, writing out all the 32k lines. This is all but satisfying, as this should not change anything. (nor should sscanf affect the file descriptor)

Could you please help me solve this problem properly? I don't really like the idea to call it "[magic](http://catb.org/jargon/html/magic-story.html)".

Thanks in advance,

Comment: `char data = 0;` --> `int data = 0;` because `%3d` for int.

Comment: I tested with gcc and it works fine (`gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 4.8.4`)

Comment: compile it with `-Wall` `-Wextra` gcc should warn about wrong usage of `scanf` and `printf`

Comment: Yep, changing type of "data" to int (and casting it as a char later when needed) seems to have solved it. Thanks a lot, even though I still don't get why this would set the file descriptor to NULL.

Comment: *I still don't get why this would set the file descriptor to NULL.*  Undefined behavior is *undefined*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those lines are inconsistent.

```
char data = 0;
/* ... */
    sscanf(buf, "%5d,%3d\n", &addr, &data);
```

`data` is a `char`, so it is 1 memory byte.
You're running on linux, if you have a 64-bit machine, `int` is probably 8 bytes. So your `sscanf()` does a memory overflow that can do anything: overwriting other variables, corrupting the stack, etc... Setting another variable to `null` is probably one of the less disastrous things it can do.

Comment: As BLUEPIXY mentioned earlier, correct. Thanks for the additional explanation. :)